# .htaccess - redirect domain.pl/something to domain.eu/something-else

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I want to make redirect from old links to new, for example:

domain.pl/cat -> domain.eu/dog

The problem is, that I don't want to redirect domain.eu/cat to domain.eu/dog - how to write correct htaccess rule for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: It is not working for redirect domain.pl/cat to domain.eu/dog

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Now I understand, for my question solution is:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat$ http://domain.eu/dog [R=301,L]

Thank you for your help :)